# How to label result tables in multiple SELECT output

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, ssms, alias

I wrote a simple dummy procedure to check the data that saved in the database. When I run my procedure it output the data as below.

[image]

I want to label the tables. Then even a QA person can identify the data which gives as the result. How can I do it?

**Update : ** This procedure is running manually through Management Studios. Nothing to do with my application. Because all I want to check is whether the data has inserted/updated properly.

*For better clarity, I want to show the table names above the table as a **label**.*

Comment: do that with the programming language that calls it, knowing the ordering. So, it's a front-end issue.

Comment: This procedure is run manually in SQL Server Management Studios. So, No programming language is affecting to this process :(

Comment: Dare I ask if you have a front-end app? :p

Comment: I vaguely remember looking for a way to do that some years ago and came up with nothing. you can add another select statement before each result set that will only select the name of the next result set (`SELECT 'Employee'`), of course this means your output will contain twice as many result sets.

If you do find a way to actually label the result sets please share it as an answer to your own post.

Comment: or jam a string down column one for each

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems doesn't fit for programming question and got downvote as well.

Comment: @CrazyNinja you know you can simply delete your question instead of closing it, right?

Comment: @ZoharPeled I can't delete it as it has some answers for it :( I tried it

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add another column to the table, and name it so it will be distinguished by who reads them :)

```
 Select 'Employee' as TABLE_NAME, * from Employee
```

Output will look like this:

```
| TABLE_NAME | ID | Number | ...
------------------------------
| Employee   | 1  | 123    | ...
```

Or you can call the column 'Employee'

```
SELECT 'Employee' AS 'Employee', * FROM employee
```

The output will look like this:

```
| Employee | ID | Number | ...
------------------------------
| Employee | 1  | 123    | ...
```

Comment: This is actually adding an **Extra Column** to the result set for *each record*. But still this is helpful.

Answer (score 3):

I like to stick a whole nother result set that looks like a label or title between the result sets with real data.

```sql
SELECT 0 AS [Our Employees:]
WHERE 1 = 0

-- Your first "Employees" query goes here

SELECT 0 AS [Our Departments:]
WHERE 1 = 0

-- Now your second real "Departments" query goes here

-- ...and so on...
```

Ends up looking like this:

[image: Hacky labelled result sets in SSMS]

It's a bit looser-formatted with more whitespace than I like, but is the best I've come up with so far.

Answer (score 2):

Add an extra column, whiches **name** (not value!) is the label.

```
SELECT 'Employee' AS "Employee", e.* FROM employee e
```

The output will look like this:

```
| Employee | ID | Number | ...
------------------------------
| Employee | 1  | 123    | ...
```

By doing so, you will see the label, **even if the result does not contain rows**.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no way of labeling any SELECT query output in SQL Server or SSMS. The very similar thing was once needed in my experience a few years ago. We settled for using a work around:

> Adding another table which contains the list of table aliases.

Here is what we did:
We appended the list of tables with another table in the beginning of the data set. So the first Table will look as follows:

> **Name**
>   Employee
>   Department
>   Courses
>   Class
>   Attendance

In c# while reading the tables, you can iterate through the first table first and assign TableName to all tables in the DataSet further.

Answer (score 0):

This is best done using Reporting Services and creating a simple report. You can then email this report daily if you wish.